# Undefined offset in codeigniter inside a loop

Tags: php

I am have a php functionality shown below. Only a snippet is shown

```
$item_err = array();
for($is = 2; $is <= 10; $is ++)
{
  if($order_no)
  {
    $check_ordr_data =  $this->admin_model->checkOrderNo( array('order_no'=>trim($order_no)) );
    if (( $check_ordr_data ) > 0) 
    {
      echo "hello";
      $item_err[$is] .= ' Order Number  already exists in database ' . $order_no ;
      print_r($item_err);
      echo 'hi'; exit;
    }

  }
}
```

The output what i am getting is

> hello A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 2
>
> Filename: controllers/network.php
>
> Line Number: 502
>
> Array ( [2] => Order Number already exists in database PO-2018-01 ) hi

I am not able to find out what is wrong in the code snippet. Any help appreciated.

Comment: undefined offset means that an array have ran out of bounds.
Ie, the array size is smaller than the index that you are trying to fetch an object from. Hence for($is = 2; $is <= 10; $is ++) is the problem

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
$item_err[$is] .= ' Order Number  already exists in database ' . $order_no ;
```

You are doing `.=` which mean you want to concatenate the value. But `$item_err[$is]` might be unset, resulting in your error.

You should just use a regular `=`

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Error is because u r trying to set a value for a non exist key in the `$item_err`*

**Replace**

```
$item_err[$is] .=
```

**with**

```
$item_err[] =
```

*The whole code should be like this:*

```
$item_err = array();
    for($is = 2; $is <= 10; $is++)
    {
      if($order_no)
      {
          $check_ordr_data =  $this->admin_model->checkOrderNo(array('order_no' => trim($order_no)));
          if (( $check_ordr_data ) > 0) 
          {
              echo "hello";
              $item_err[] = ' Order Number  already exists in database ' . $order_no ;
              print_r($item_err);
              echo 'hi'; exit;
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Message: Undefined offset: 2

This error is caused by `$item_err[$is]`. At the start of the loop the value `$is` is 2. When appending the error, you are trying to set a value for a key that does not exist in the `$item_err` array.

What you could do to solve this is append to the list of errors without worrying about the index.
`$item_err[] = ' Order Number  already exists in database ' . $order_no;`